# Jenkins Crashes after update

Tags: jenkins

I installed the latest Jenkins update, which is 1.588. Now jenkins crashes sometimes when try to open the confifguration page or console output page.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.588.jar!/hudson/model/Run/console.jelly:65:27: <j:whitespace> PermGen space
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:103)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$12.dispatch(MetaClass.java:391)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:86)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.588.jar!/hudson/model/Run/console.jelly:65:27: <j:whitespace> PermGen space
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.OtherwiseTag.doTag(OtherwiseTag.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CompressTag.doTag(CompressTag.java:44)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.writeHtmlTo(AnnotatedLargeText.java:175)
    at hudson.model.Run.writeLogTo(Run.java:1397)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.parser.EscapingExpression.evaluate(EscapingExpression.java:24)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ExpressionScript.run(ExpressionScript.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.WhitespaceTag.doTag(WhitespaceTag.java:48)
```

Is there anyway to fix this other than restarting jenkins all the time?

Comment: Jenkins has a unique plugin source: https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json . I think it is too unstable. The best would be to have an alternate URL managed with stability in mind. Too offen (3th a month), plugins have red alterts like `Warning: This plugin requires... incompatible with previous version... need to reconfigure...` . Jenkins configuration is so painful, I don't want to reconfigure every month!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error log:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

You can fix this by increasing the amount of PermGen space as a command line option when starting Jenkins. The [Out of Memory Errors Jenkins wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors) describes the specific command line options.

Answer (score -1):

I had to uninstall the OpenShift Plugin which was giving this issue.

This is also one of the solution. delete plugin from plugin folder also.